# How can I get top name from aggregation count in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql

I have 3 tables

1. users
2. coin_histories
3. coins

Users table data looks like

```
id | email 
------------------
1  | abc@test.com
```

coin_histories

```
   id | from_user_id | coin_id 
   ----------------------
   1  |    1    | 2
   1  |    1    | 2   
   1  |    1    | 3
```

coins

```
   id | name 
------------
    2 | Lira
    3 | Bitcoin
```

My expected output

```
Email         | total_given   | top_coin_name 
============================================
abc@test.com  | 3             | lira
```

After written below query I am able to get total_given count with email

```
SELECT
    users.email
    from_user_id,
    count (coin_id)
FROM
    coin_histories
INNER JOIN users 
    ON coin_histories.from_user_id = users.id
GROUP BY
    from_user_id,
    users.email
ORDER BY 
    count desc
```

How can I get top coin name which has given by an user ?

Comment: just You need to inner join the coins table, after that you can get top_coin_name by max of name.

Comment: @selvarajmas In inner join how can I map the coin_id in ON ?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I need all coin count group by users not only hight count, Here I also need coin name too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can calculate the total number of coins given and the highest number for each user in a single statement:

```
select from_user_id, 
       coin_id,
       sum(count(*)) over (partition by from_user_id) as total_given,
       dense_rank() over (partition by from_user_id order by count(*) desc) as rnk
from coin_histories
group by from_user_id, coin_id
```

This first calculates the number of coins given per user and coin id. The [window functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial-window.htmlhttps://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial-window.html) (`over (...)`) are evaluated *after* the `group by`. So the `sum()` gives us the total number of rows per user and the `dense_rank()` evaluates the rank per coins given  so that we can pick the highest one.

For your ample data, the query above returns the following:

```
from_user_id | coin_id | total_given | rnk
-------------+---------+-------------+----
           1 |       2 |           3 |   1
           1 |       3 |           3 |   2
```

This query can be joined against the users and coins table to get what you want:

```
select u.id, u.email, tp.total_given, c.name 
from users u
  join (
    select from_user_id, 
           coin_id,
           sum(count(*)) over (partition by from_user_id) as total_given,
           dense_rank() over (partition by from_user_id order by count(*) desc) as rnk
    from coin_histories
    group by from_user_id, coin_id 
  ) tp on tp.from_user_id = u.id and tp.rnk = 1
  join coins c on c.id = tp.coin_id
;
```

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=e453e98e90a82f6be365861db5dc8dff)